# Java String checked for null value suddenly becomes null

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am using the [StreamGobbler](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) to consume the output of a process.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
int count = 0;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null);
{
    if(line == null){
         System.out.println("This shouldn't print out.");
    }
}
```

I think it is obvious that the String "This shouldn't print out." should not print out, but it does. I have no idea what further data to provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the while expression, which terminates it, so the following braces are treated as a generic statement block.

Basically, the semicolon causes it to be treated like this.

```
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {} //do nothing

if(line == null){
     System.out.println("This shouldn't print out.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from while loop, it makes the loop do nothing and then move forward to the if block which will be true. That's the reason it prints